# AlarmManager: AlarmReceiver works but not notification appears

Tags: android, kotlin, alarmmanager

I'm stuck on a part of the project I'm developing and can't get past here. Let's see if anyone knows where I'm going wrong.

My project is to make an Alarm with the AlarmManager. I am making modules so that I can call these modules in other modules like the view or the viewmodel, but this is not important.

I am using a clean layered architecture:
When I create an alarm I collect the ID of this alarm (I am creating them and saving them in the ROOM locally that I am making in a module called Database).

The problem I'm having is that when I create or update it by setting a new time for it to ring, it goes through the AlarmReceiver but I don't get any notification or popup in my table.

I have checked permissions of the tablet in this particular program, in the manifest if I was missing some permission but nothing, nothing works. They are created fine, they update fine, they sound when they are supposed to sound but the notification does not work, when it is going through it and apparently no error comes out.

This is my AlarmReceiver code:

```
class AlarmReceiver : BroadcastReceiver() {
    private lateinit var notificationManager: NotificationManagerCompat

    @SuppressLint("MissingPermission")
    override fun onReceive(context: Context, intent: Intent) {
        createNotificationChannel(context)
        val alarmId = intent.getLongExtra(ALARM_ID_KEY, -1L)

        if (alarmId == -1L) {
            Log.e("AlarmReceiver", "Error: no se proporcionó un ID de alarma válido.")
            return
        }

        val tapResultIntent = Intent(context, AlarmHandler::class.java).apply {
            flags = Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP
        }
        val pendingIntent: PendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, tapResultIntent, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT or PendingIntent.FLAG_IMMUTABLE)

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(context, "to_do_list")
            .setContentTitle("Alarma")
            .setContentText("¡La alarma ha sonado!")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.notification_icon)
            .setAutoCancel(true)
            .setPriority(NotificationCompat.PRIORITY_HIGH)
            .setContentIntent(pendingIntent)
            .build()

        notificationManager.notify(alarmId.toInt(), notification)
        Log.d("AlarmReceiver", "Alarma con ID $alarmId recibida.")
    }

    private fun createNotificationChannel(context: Context) {
        val importance = NotificationManager.IMPORTANCE_HIGH
        val channel = NotificationChannel("to_do_list", "Tasks Notification Channel", importance).apply {
            description = "Notification for Tasks"
        }
        notificationManager = NotificationManagerCompat.from(context)
        notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
    }
}
```

Y este mi AlarmHandler:

```
class AlarmHandler(
    private val createAlarmUseCase: CreateAlarmUseCase,
    private val updateAlarmUseCase: UpdateAlarmUseCase,
    private val deleteAlarmUseCase: DeleteAlarmUseCase,
    private val getAllAlarmUseCase: GetAllAlarmUseCase,
    private val deleteAllAlarmUseCase: DeleteAllAlarmUseCase,
    private val getAlarmByIdUseCase: GetAlarmByIdUseCase,
    private val context: Context
) : IAlarmHandler {

    private val alarmManager = context.getSystemService(AlarmManager::class.java)

    private fun setAlarmUsingAlarmManager(id: Long?, date: Date?, context: Context) {
        val intent = Intent(context, AlarmReceiver::class.java).apply {
            putExtra(ALARM_ID_KEY, id)
        }

        val pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(
            context,
            id?.toInt() ?: 0,
            intent,
            ALARM_PENDING_INTENT_FLAG // Custom flag defined as a constant
        )

        val triggerTime = date?.time ?: System.currentTimeMillis()
        alarmManager.setExactAndAllowWhileIdle(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, triggerTime, pendingIntent)
    }


    override suspend fun createAlarm(
        name: String,
        description: String,
        date: Date,
        isActive: Boolean,
        replay: JSONObject
    ) {
        val alarmId = createAlarmUseCase.create(name, description, date, isActive, replay)
        setAlarmUsingAlarmManager(alarmId, date, context)
    }

    override suspend fun updateAlarm(
        id: Long,
        name: String?,
        description: String?,
        date: Date?,
        isActive: Boolean?,
        replay: JSONObject?
    ) {
        // Call the use case to update the existing alarm
        updateAlarmUseCase.update(id, name, description, date, isActive, replay)

        if (isActive == true && date != null) {
            setAlarmUsingAlarmManager(id, date, context)
        }

    }

    override suspend fun deleteAlarm(id: Long) {
        // Call the use case to delete the alarm
        deleteAlarmUseCase.delete(id)
    }

    override suspend fun getAllAlarm(): Flow<List<AlarmEntity>> {
        return getAllAlarmUseCase.getAll()
    }

    override suspend fun getAlarmById(id: Long): Flow<AlarmEntity?> {
        return getAlarmByIdUseCase.getById(id)
    }

    override suspend fun deleteAllAlarm() {
        deleteAllAlarmUseCase.deleteAll()
    }
}
```

As I said, everything works fine apparently, in the logs nothing strange appears, the final log of the AlarmReceiver is called where the id of my alarm appears and nothing.

This is my manifest:

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.POST_NOTIFICATIONS" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SCHEDULE_EXACT_ALARM" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WAKE_LOCK" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.VIBRATE" />
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE" />

    <application>
        <receiver android:name=".interactors.AlarmReceiver" />
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Someone can help me please?

Trying to make an Alarm with AlarmManager. I expected a notification popup but doesn't appear.

Comment: Someone helps please?